# Show that there is no such entire function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)|>e^{|z|}$ for all $|z|>100$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have been struggling on the following problem:
Show that there is no such entire function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)|>e^{|z|}$ for all $|z|>100$.

I've tried to define at first $g(z)=1/f(z)$ and use liouville theorem but $f$ might have zeros in $\{|z|\leq 100\}$.
I also thought about using the argument theorem.

I would really appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Try factoring out $z - a$ for each zero $a$ of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that such a function exists.  Then all zeros of $f$ lie in the ball of radius 100, and hence
$f$ has finitely many zeros.  Letting $p$ be a polynomial with the same zeros as $f$, with the same multiplicities, we
deduce that $g(z):= p(z)/f(z)$  is an entire function with
$$
  |g(z)|\leq
  \frac{|p(z)|}{|f(z)|}
  \leq \frac{|p(z)|}{e^{|z|}}
  $$
for $|z|>100$.
Since $e^{|z|}$ grows faster than any polynomial,  we deduce that $g$ is bounded, and hence constant by Liouville's
theorem.  Consequently $f$ is polynomial, but it is clear that no polynomial can satisfy the hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was needed