# Show that there is no such entire function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)|>e^{|z|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491611/show-that-there-is-no-such-entire-function-fz-such-that-fzez-for), but I did not quite understand the solution.
Is it possible to solve this question without a polynomial?

We have to prove that there is no entire function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)|$ > $e^{|z|}$
for all $\{z:|z| > 100 \}$

If we assume that $f(z)$ is entire function and we know that $f(z) > 0$ because $f(z)$ >
$e^{|z|}$
Let $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$

then

$\frac{1}{|f(z)|} \leq \frac{1}{e^{|z|}}$

And that's where I got stuck

Comment: It follows that $\lim_{z\to\infty}g(z)=0$. So the Maximum Modulus Theorem implies _what_???

Comment: $g(z)$ has maximum on the boundary $|z|=100$ and $g(z)$ is bounded outside the circle by $\frac{1}{e^{100}}$?

Comment: You can’t write $f(z) >0$ unless you have some argument that $f(z)$ is real.

Comment: @Randall So how can we solve that?

Comment: You can’t.  There is no reason for it to be real.  Note that the other argument never uses this.

Comment: @Randll So how do you approach the proof?

Comment: The only other argument I can think of is to apply the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem, after arguing that $f$ must have an essential singularity at infinity.

Comment: You want to make the argument on the modulus of the function.   All you need are some vertical bars.

Comment: @Randall
I don't quite understand you to be honest, could you write me the beginning of the proof and what should I use??